# What/where is get_Zero in F#'s int?

Tags: .net, f#, compiler-errors, functional-programming, f#-scripting

I'm just learning F#, and while playing at [tryfsharp.org](http://www.tryfsharp.org) I noticed that if I change this code:

```
[0..100]
|> List.sum
```

to

```
["A"; "B"; "D"]
|> List.sum
```

I get the following error:

```
The type 'string' does not support the operator 'get_Zero'
```

([Here's the script that you can run/amend in your browser](http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/dantup/get_Zero.fsx), though it only seems to work in IE for me!)

When I checked [the definition of List.sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353634.aspx); it says that the type must have a static member called Zero. This seems to explain the error; except for the fact that I can't see any member called Zero on int!

So; where is this Zero member that applies to ints? I can't see it in intellisense if I type `int.`, nor in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233210.aspx), which says int is just a .NET System.Int32 (which [doesn't seem to have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32_fields.aspx) a static Zero property).

(note: it does say "Operator" and not "Member" in the error; which may be related; though the List.sum definition does just say "member").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Digging in F# source code, [List.sum (and Seq.sum)](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/4493a116ba6862ff0c1d08b7e1c73c6ff8b4e8af/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1353) is using GenericZero:

```
let inline sum (source: seq< (^a) >) : ^a = 
    use e = source.GetEnumerator() 
    let mutable acc = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero< (^a) >
    while e.MoveNext() do
        acc <- Checked.(+) acc e.Current
    acc
```

On the other hand, F# compiler builds a table to lookup zero values of all built-in numeric types before querying Zero members. The relevant bits are in [this line](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/94117fc51a8855765d972227646e7fc9b22d96b9/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L2378) and the code fragment below.

```
    type GenericZeroDynamicImplTable<'T>() = 
        static let result : 'T = 
            // The dynamic implementation
            let aty = typeof<'T>
            if   aty.Equals(typeof<sbyte>)      then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0y)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<int16>)      then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0s)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<int32>)      then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<int64>)      then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0L)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<nativeint>)  then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0n)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<byte>)       then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0uy)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<uint16>)     then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0us)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<uint32>)     then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0u)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<uint64>)     then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0UL)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<unativeint>) then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0un)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<decimal>)    then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0M)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<float>)      then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0.0)
            elif aty.Equals(typeof<float32>)    then unboxPrim<'T> (box 0.0f)
            else 
               let pinfo = aty.GetProperty("Zero")
               unboxPrim<'T> (pinfo.GetValue(null,null))
        static member Result : 'T = result
```

That said, if you would like to use `List.sum` on user-defined types, you need to define Zero member explicitly. Note that `Zero` doesn't make much sense in case of string type.

Comment: `Zero` doesn't make sense on `string` if you think of it in terms of numerics; however, it does make sense to have a `Zero` member on `string` which returns the empty string, as that would make `string` a monoid under string concatenation.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Ofcourse, I didn't expect the code to work for a string array, I was just trying to understand how things worked. I'm curious why this magic Zero member that seems to be defined in the code linked doesn't seem accessible/visible in any of the intellisense as a visible member; is this just because it's not defined in a way that's visible outside of the type/module/etc.?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Yes, that's exactly the reason. It's only for the built-in, primitive numeric types in the list @pad posted -- any other types will have an actual property called `Zero` with a getter (`get`) method you can call (i.e., `get_Zero`).

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) is the best place to look for this sort of information.  I believe that this should be covered in section 14.5.4.1 (Simulation of Solutions for Member Constraints), but it looks like `Zero` isn't actually mentioned there, which is almost certainly a spec bug.